# How to alter the formatting of a single member of my type in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a set of C# classes that each have a ulong member or two. Powershell outputs these by default as 10-base numbers, but I'd like to show them as hex numbers with a 0x prefix. I'm trying to figure out how to do this right with .ps1xml files.

The first thing I tried was to add a types.ps1xml file that adds a script property with the same name as the one I want to replace. Works fine if I give it a different name (i.e. add a new member) but crashes the ISE if I use the same name as an existing one, like this:

```
<Members>
    <ScriptProperty>
        <Name>ForeignId</Name>
        <GetScriptBlock>'0x{0:x16}' -f $this.ForeignId</GetScriptBlock>
    </ScriptProperty>      
</Members>
```

I assume this is an infinite recursion issue.

Maybe what I really want to do is change the formatting! So I started looking at making a format.ps1xml and using `<FormatString>`, but now it seems I need to define the formatting completely. I must specify every member I want, and I must do it for all the views I might want. Well, that's a lot of work..

I just want to change the formatting of a single member without adding a new member. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ran across this a couple of days ago.  Maybe useful?

http://poshoholic.com/2008/07/05/essential-powershell-define-default-properties-for-custom-objects/

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's pretty interesting. I could see using that for my own custom types. Unfortunately doesn't help with this question because I'm trying to alter the default formatting of .NET types out of the control of my posh script. I need a way to alter the global formatting for a type (the article is geared towards per-instance) and don't know of any way to do this aside from ps1xml files. I suspect I can do what I want with a ps1xml, it's just that there are so many features in there I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it do this specific task.

Comment: Wish I had a better answer.  I'm sure it can be done using the ps1xml file.  I've messed with it some, and think I'd rather bikini wax a wolverine.